# Index state never change to ENABLED on Titan with Amazon DynamoDB backend

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan

I'm trying to use composite index on DynamoDB and the index never switches from from `INSTALLED` to `REGISTERED` state.

Here is the code I used to create it

```
        graph.tx().rollback(); //Never create new indexes while a transaction is active
        TitanManagement mgmt=graph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey=getOrCreateIfNotExist(mgmt, "propertyKeyName");
        String indexName = makePropertyKeyIndexName(propertyKey);

        if (mgmt.getGraphIndex(indexName)==null) {
            mgmt.buildIndex(indexName, Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
            mgmt.commit();
            graph.tx().commit();
            ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, indexName).status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED).call(); 
        }else {
            mgmt.rollback();
        }
```

A sample of the log is:

> ...
>   ...
>
> 612775 [main] INFO 
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher
>   - Some key(s) on index myIndex do not currently have status REGISTERED: type=INSTALLED 613275 [main] INFO 
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher
>   - Some key(s) on index typeIndex do not currently have status REGISTERED: type=INSTALLED 613275 [main] INFO 
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher
>   - Timed out (PT1M) while waiting for index typeIndex to converge on status REGISTERED

Comment: Hey M-T-A, were you able to get this working, I am having a similar problems when used with titan + cassandra.

Comment: No, hope to get a response from Titan guys on this.

Comment: What I have observed is the index transfers to enabled state if there is no data for the given label, but if there is some data already existing then it gets stuck in the installed state

Comment: Also, this is the same behaviour even when there is no other instance open which is stalled/inactive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waiting for a longer time does the trick. Example:

```
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, propertyKeyIndexName)
                    .status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED)
                    .timeout(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES) // set timeout to 10 min
                    .call();
```