# TitanDB - ElasticSearch mixed index search not enabling

Tags: database, graph, titan, gremlin

**TitanDB 1.0.0** (on top of DynamoDB)

**Gremlin 3**

I've created a **mixedIndex** in my TitanDB instance (only single machine - not cluster.) Reindexed the data. Called `updateIndex(myIndex, SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX)` and it's stuck in this.

`GraphIndexStatusReport[success=false, indexName='timestampIndex', targetStatus=REGISTERED, notConverged={timestamp=ENABLED}, converged={}, elapsed=PT1M0.068S]`

There are no active transactions when I call `g.getOpenTransactions()`

`mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("timestampIndex"), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX)` returns null - not sure if related but if I try to call `.get()` on this is fails

I've created **compositeIndex** before and it worked fine

Comment: Did you try to change the log level for more details?

Comment: What happens when you try to insert data after doing this? What about trying to retrieve data? Are you actually getting any errors or warn messages saying the query requires iterating over all vertices?

Comment: No it doesn't give me any warnings but to sort a set of 80 vertices and extract first 20 things takes about 1500ms which I find super long as it will only get longer the bigger the size of the set. So my idea was, index them in that order so I don't have to do any ordering, just request the range and it'll be much faster.

Comment: This could be a possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088574/index-state-never-change-to-enabled-on-titan-with-amazon-dynamodb-backend).